# sticky footer slide up to reveal

Tags: jquery, css

What I am trying to do is create a sticky footer that is half hidden but will slide up to reveal the hidden part on the end of the page scroll. The sticky footer itself, this I can do easy enough. But, I want it to appear as if the end of the page catches the footer and pulls up the hidden part. I hope I explained that correctly. Seems I should be able to figure this out, but Im not. Obviously I need to use jQuery but not sure what functions to use. I searched everywhere for a tut or something but to no avail. If someone might point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You will have to provide more than just a 'please help'. You look like cheating your homework.

Comment: 1) That wasn't smartass, it was an analogy (and an accurate one). 2). SO is a code discussion site. Code is nearly always required, indicating that you have some understanding of what you're doing and that you've made some effort.

Comment: @isherwood I think he was referring to my comment

Comment: @andrew We can direct OP in a more constructive way. Please review this post as to why these sorts of comments are discouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code, but I will try and send you in the right direction...

You don't technically need jQuery to do this, but it may make it easier. What you need to do to make the footer catch and pull up from the bottom is hook in to the document scroll event:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    // if bottom of page is reached, slide up the footer
})
```

You can know when and how much to move the footer by comparing window scroll, window height and document height.

Comment: @JimmyKnoll - come back with code and I'd be happy to help more.

Comment: [jsfiddle -my code](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmy69/kReyu/)    so i decided to just let a div sit on the bottom of the screen and when the real footer slides up that one dispapears basically giving the illusion of what i was after.  Not sure what all that above is all about since i never asked for any code. For my first time posting here this turned into a bad first impression. @Kevin, thanks for the decent answer. I was trying to figure out post correctly here but hmmmm